# jaydata replace local sqlite data with fresh server data

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jaydata

With my current project i am using node webkit to make a desktop app. the app must be able to work offline after it has retrieved server data (odata).

At this time, I got a solution kind of working, I recreate the DB with the `DropAllExistingTables` flag and add my fresh server entities to this new DB when it resolves. this works but its very slow.

```
function clearLocal() {
            var defer = $.Deferred();

            self.OfflineEntities.onReady(function () {
                self.OfflineEntities = new eveosliteEntities({
                    name: 'sqLite',
                    databaseName: 'OFFLINESTACK',
                    dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropAllExistingTables
                });

                self.OfflineEntities.onReady(function () {
                    defer.resolve(true);
                });
            });

            return defer.promise();
        };
```

Any ideas on a way to speed this up?

Comment: which part of the sync is slow? the database re-creation or the retrieval of the records?

Comment: the re-creation bit is slow-ish, records retrieval is light speed! Am I doing this the right way? I mean, I can somehow cope with it being a bit slow but really... @Robesz, is this the way you would go about this? thanks!